# Python np.argmin: how can I get both the index and value of the minimum item?

Tags: python, numpy

I use this to get the index of the minimum value, however I want to get the minimum value as well without compute haversine function again.

```
idx = np.argmin(haversine(line_station.D_Lng, line_station.D_Lat,\
                          row2.O_Lng, row2.O_Lat))
```

Is there anything like:

```
idx, value = np.argmin(haversine(line_station.D_Lng, line_station.D_Lat, \
                                 row2.O_Lng, row2.O_Lat))
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't think that there is one function in `numpy` that returns both `min` and `argmin`, but you can do that in two steps, and still apply `haversine` only once:

```
vec=haversine(line_station.D_Lng, line_station.D_Lat, row2.O_Lng, row2.O_Lat)
idx = np.argmin(vec)
minimum=vec[idx]
```